# Removing first come element first continuously

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the following demo. How can I fadeout/retire each `.point` based on the its age after 5 seconds? (fadeout oldest `.point` element between existing in the page).

What I need to do is to remove first come first but how can I keep track of age of elements?

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var color = '#' + (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16);
  $("#points").append('<div class="point" style="background:' + color + '"></div>');

}, 3000);
```

```css
.point {
  float: left;
  margin: 15px;
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="points"></div>
```

Comment: please add your remove code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, but maybe something like this (each point fades out 5 seconds after it appears (2 seconds after the next point appears):

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var color = '#' + (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16).padStart( 6, '0' );
  $("#points").append(
    $('<div class="point" style="background:' + color + '"></div>')
    .delay( 5000 ).fadeOut( function ( ) { 
      $(this).show().css( 'visibility', 'hidden' );
    } )
  );
}, 3000);
```

```css
.point {
  float: left;
  margin: 15px;
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="points"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use css animation, delay 5 seconds, then fade.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var color = '#' + (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16);
  $("#points").append('<div class="point" style="background:' + color + '"></div>');

}, 3000);
```

```css
.point {
  float: left;
  margin: 15px;
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: fade 1s 5s forwards;
  opacity:1;
}
@keyframes fade{
  0%{
    opacity:1;
  }
  100%{
    opacity:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="points"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another setInterval of 5 seconds and delete the first .point child.Check below working example.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var color = '#' + (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16);
  $("#points").append('<div class="point" style="background:' + color + '"></div>');

}, 3000);

setInterval(function() {
  $("#points .point:first-child").remove();

}, 5000);
```

```css
.point {
  float: left;
  margin: 15px;
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="points"></div>
```